# Getting a UIView Animation to play through airplay

Tags: iphone, uiviewanimation, airplay

I'm using `UIView` animation blocks to crate a slidshow of images.  I'd like to allow users to play those animations through AirPlay.  Would I somehow have to save a video file and play that or is there something more clever that could be done?

Comment: What version of the iOS SDK are you using? To my knowledge mirroring is only available in iOS 5 and the current implementation of AirPlay only supports media streaming.

Comment: I wanted to do this with 4.3.  Will look into mirroring.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 5, user will be able to [mirror the screen using AirPlay](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios5/features.html#more) to there other AirPlay devices (mainly the Apple TV).

In the current stable version of iOS (4.3.5 as of this writing), I don't think that can be made (except, like you said, with a video file).